# Debug application with PID in cf

Tags: node.js, linux, debugging, cloud-foundry

I've node application and I use the following guide to debug it which works great
https://codeburst.io/an-easy-way-to-debug-node-js-apps-in-cloud-foundry-22f559d44516

Now I've a bit more complex scenario which one application is spawn **other node application** which I want to debug (the spawned application ) , in the `cf top` I see this app `PID` (of the spawned app) but my question if there is a way to debug it also ? both app running in the same container .

I was able to debug the master app but not the spawned app..., any idea how ?

I was able to ssh the main app, we are using cf 2.98 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything CloudFoundry-specific that needs to be done to make this work.  The process described at the link you provided is showing how you can launch an application with the `node --inspect` flag, create an SSH tunnel to the port where `node` is listening and then attach to it remotely over the SSH tunnel.

If you're spawning subprocesses, I would suggest that you make sure those subprocesses, assuming they're also running Node, have the `--inspect=<port>` flag passed to them.  In this case, you will need to set a port because the default port 9229 used by `--inspect` is already taken by your main process.

I don't know if your subprocesses are short or long-lived, but you may need to log the inspect port assigned to them somewhere so that you know which port to connect to so that you inspect a specific subprocess.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks 1+, Can you please explain how should I do the' --inspect=<port>'  ? I need somehow to inspect the app port for debug, in addition, for regular app I use `cf ssh -N -T -L 9229:127.0.0.1:9229 <applicationName>` what would be the application main here? the main app name ?( the app that was pushed)

Comment: So if you spawn one child application and pass `--inspect=9228` to it as an argument then you should be able `cf ssh -N -T -L 9228:127.0.0.1:9228`.  You can then use your local debugger to connect to 9228 and debug the child process.  How you spawn your child processes or how you assign port numbers to them is up to you.  This Github issue has an example of spawning a process and passing the `--inspect` argument linked from it -> https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8690#issuecomment-335354799